# Correct way to deal with multiple forms generated by one controller and action?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I'm using the Zend Framework and I'm about to hack up some of my controller code to do something that seems like there should be a pattern for already.

Currently when I only have one form, the form's action points back to the same action and controller as the one that generated the page. The controller's action function then verifies the form and if verification succeeds, does the desired action. If verification fails, it doesn't perform the action and the page is re-generated using the form that was validated so error messages appear in the correct place.

My situation now is that I have an action/controller that creates two forms and a list of items to the view for display. The view displays the list (say, for example, a list of users) and shows the forms (add user and create role - just as an example). What is the correct "Zend Framework" way to handle this? Should each of the forms' actions be pointing back to the same action/controller? If so, how does one handle validation?

My guess (and how I'm going to proceed for now) is to point both forms back to the controller, figure out which form was submitted, validate that form only, perform action on validation, or re-generate view on failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let each form have different submit name and validate them based on that. But beware, when you validate wrong form, the error messages will appear ;) So test carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the two forms to the two different actions of the same controller, and extract the list generation to a third method, and call it from indexAction, and the both form submission actions.